# Does a water filter's "service flow rate" refer to the filtration rate?

Tags: shower

I found this [water filter catalogue](https://www.puroitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TM-EN-PF-GAC_AG-Rev2017.01.pdf). Is the number 3,4 which is service flow rate referring to the filtration rate which it can filter 3,4m^3 of water per hour?

Thank you for reading and have a nice day

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the screen shot you showed us:

[image: OPs image with units of measurement highlighted]

Yes, that is *maximum* m<sup>3</sup>/hr or "cubic meters per hour" assuming (footnote #3) a clean filter bed. The row below indicates the *recommended maximum* service flow for (footnote #4) "adequate" filtration, with the highest flow rate (line above) available "intermittently".

Of course, since this was produced by an American company and is in American English, this is a valid question, especially since the line just above this indicates "Filter media **(cuft)**" (indicating cubic feet). It's a bit of a mish-mosh of units of measurement, but at least they're identified.

This, however, is pretty obvious.